# How to return the socket status for the validating the port scanning

Tags: python

As a part of security testing, I am developing a script which check the connected port in the host and return `0` if the status is `true` (if its connected to the port) or else it return some error code.. so I need to include that condition in the below code under the `def getPort_on_host()` where the `result ==` should return the connected ports ..

Would be great if anyone can help me  out here...

```
import socket

class A:

    s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def getAddress():
    host= raw_input("Enter the Host name :" )
    result = s.gethostbyname(host)
    return result

    def getPort_on_host():
    portlist =[20,23,80,912,135,445,20]
    for port in portlist:
            result = s.connect_ex((getAddress,port))

            if result ==""

            print result
            return port
            s.close()

    def getService():
            status = s.getserverbyport(getPOrt_on_host)
            print status
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes - watch your indentation. The levels for functions all have to be indented past the function or it won't work.
Same for conditional statements: `for`, `if`, `else`, etc. all need to have one indentation level below them. All these statements need
a colon after them as well.

Next, it seems like you might be trying to pass `s` as an instance variable (i.e. global to the class) which means you should
denote it with `self.`. If you continue to use the class structure you should also create an `__init__` method. 
You will also need to pass that as a parameter in all your methods. Also note that if you use
`return` in a Python function, it will not execute code below that. Here your `s.close()` is unreachable.

When passing a method, if you want to pass the method object itself, calling the method name is fine. If you want to 
pass the value returned by the function you will need to add parenthesis to the method name, i.e. `result = self.s.connect_ex((self.getAddress(),port))`

I see that you are calling the `gethostbyname` on the socket object when you need to call that on the socket interface itself.
You should convert the hostname on a different variable, then call the `connect_ex` on the socket object after.

Be aware that in that `for` loop you are passing the function every single time as well. So it will ask for a host name each time.

Here is an updated version that gets you closer to where you need to be. Note that opening the host and testing each socket will take some
time for the host to be printed:

```
import socket

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def getAddress(self):
        newSocketobj = socket
        host = raw_input("Enter the Host name :" )
        result = newSocketobj.gethostbyname(host)
        print result
        return result

    def getPort_on_host(self):
        portlist =[20,23,80,912,135,445,20]
        hostname = self.getAddress()
        for port in portlist:
            status = self.s.connect_ex((hostname,port))
            print status 
            self.s.close()
        #return port

    def getService(self):
        status = self.s.getserverbyport(self.getPort_on_host)
        print status

newTest = A()
newTest.getPort_on_host()
```

Comment: Hi Jiash93.. 
I just updated the code , but getting the error as 
" File "portscanner.py", line 29, in <module>
    newTest.getPort_on_host()
  File "portscanner.py", line 18, in getPort_on_host
    result = self.connect_ex((hostname,port))
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'connect_ex'
"
iam not sure about the issues..

Thank you

Comment: You are calling `connect_ex` on the attribute, not the socket. Remember we defined the socket as `self.s`, so you have to call the method on that. The line should be:
`self.s.connect_ex((hostname, port))`
If you're not sure about how to call methods on objects or what attributes are, I highly recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)